# Diferença entre sistema operacional e plataforma móvel

Tags: terminologia, sistema-operacional, mobile

Procurei essa informação em outros lugares, mas não consegui esclarecimento sobre isso. Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre sistema operacional e plataforma móvel. Por exemplo, sempre ouço falar do **sistema operacional Android**, porém também ouço **plataforma Android**, o que me faz pensar que são a mesma coisa. Alguém pode esclarecer?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla... mas basicamente a diferença entre os dois sistemas é que o dispositivo movel tem um escopo de hardware menor (processador,memoria, dissipação de calor). sendo projetado para economizar processamento e tempo de atividade. controla e monitora qualquer atividade. sem contar em diversos sensores que são acoplados, câmera,micro,acelerômetro. isso exige um do sistema operacional o controle desses módulos instalados .. um sistema de permissões eficiente etc..

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu editei para uma melhor compreensão. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja a mesma coisa, porém vista de formas diferentes.

Quando se fala de **sistema operacional Android**, estamos nos referindo ao sistema capaz de gerenciar os recursos do hardware do telefone...

Agora quando falamos de  **plataforma Android**, podemos entender que estamos nos referindo o grau de compatibilidade que o sistema fornece em relação com hardwares & aplicativos diferentes. tirando essa responsabilidade do fabricante.

também existe a plataforma Windows(programas em .NET e afins).

Answer (score 0):

A plataforma precisa de um Sistema Operacional, a mais comum compõe-se do sistema operacional Windows em execução em um PC com processador Intel.

**Definição**:

- **Sistema Operacional** é um programa ou um conjunto de programas cuja função é gerenciar os recursos do sistema, fornecendo uma interface entre o computador e o usuário.
- **Plataforma** é o ambiente preexistente, um pedaço de software que é projetado para ser executado internamente, obedecendo às suas limitações e fazendo uso das suas instalações. O termo plataforma refere-se a uma combinação de hardware de computador e sistema operacional.

**Exemplo:**

- [Plataforma Java](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plataforma_Java), independe de sistema operacional

Fonte: Livro Sistemas Operacionais - Andrew S. Tanenbaum e wikipedia.

Comment: E existe ou não diferença entre eles? Esta é a pergunta feita e a resposta não responde de forma clara isso.

Comment: Não estou vendo a diferença pelos exemplos. Até porque android é baseado em linux, ubuntu também.

Comment: @diegofm, editei a minha resposta, você acha que precisa mudar mais alguma coisa ou conseguiu entender a diferença?